# 'fastboot devices' returns ??? (question marks) and device reboots

Tags: rom-flashing, usb, fastboot, usb-drivers

I came across this weird issue and wanted to share my findings somewhere.

At some point in the [installation process of Magisk](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html), I was required to use fastboot on Windows 10 21H2. I proceeded and downloaded the [adb plattform-tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) + [adb drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb). Previously ADB-related things of the instruction (like adb-shell) worked flawlessly.

However during the usage of fastboot I encountered these issues:

[image]

I tried different USB-cables, -ports and -drivers.. When I ran `fastboot devices` (or any other fastboot-command, it returned `????????????` (or an error) and the device restarted..

I was pretty certain that the device itself was fine, as well as the installation of ADB tools and driver. Nothing seemed to work and I only read about solutions like using a different PC, which was no option in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [this hint from cychau](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unable-to-use-fastboot.3906502/#post-79439827), I used a **USB 2.0 hub**, which showed me that it's a >`USB 2.0` related issue. Another suggestion ([from bitbox in #7](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unable-to-use-fastboot.3906502/#post-79039815)) was to restrict the system to only use USB 2.0 through BIOS settings.

Hope this helps someone in the future :)